# Calling external JS function from cascading SELECT element change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I am a jQuery noob here and I am trying to figure out how to move this script to an external .js file.  I already tried copying it and referencing on the page but it doesn't seem to work.

What am I missing here?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#YearD').change(function () {
        var selectedYear = $(this).val();
        if (selectedYear != null && selectedYear != '') {
            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("Months")', { year: selectedYear }, function (months) {
                var monthsSelect = $('#Month');
                monthsSelect.empty();
                $.each(months, function (index, month) {
                    monthsSelect.append($('<option/>', {
                        value: month.value,
                        text: month.text
                    }));
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#Month').change(function () {
    var selectedMonth = $(this).val();
    if (selectedMonth != null && selectedMonth != '') {
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("Days")', { month: selectedMonth }, function (days) {
            var daysSelect = $('#Day');
            daysSelect.empty();
            if (days == 0) {
                daysSelect.css("visibility", "hidden");
            }
            else {
                daysSelect.css("visibility", "visible");
            }
            $.each(days, function (index, day) {
                daysSelect.append($('<option/>', {
                    value: day.value,
                    text: day.text
                }));
            });
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
   // your code
})
```

You should do,

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/myfile.js'></script>
```

in your html file.

And in your myfile.js file (which resides at `scripts` folder)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   // your code
})
```

Notice there's not `<script>` tags in myfile.js file.

Also, do remember your code is using `jQuery`, so reference your `myfile.js` after you reference `jQuery.js` file.

e.g.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/myfile.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Also, place your code in `$(document).ready`. Your second code executes before dom is ready and will throw error.

It should be like this (in your myfile.js)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#YearD').change(function () {
        var selectedYear = $(this).val();
        if (selectedYear != null && selectedYear != '') {
            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("Months")', { year: selectedYear }, function (months) {
                var monthsSelect = $('#Month');
                monthsSelect.empty();
                $.each(months, function (index, month) {
                    monthsSelect.append($('<option/>', {
                        value: month.value,
                        text: month.text
                    }));
                });
            });
        }
    });
    $('#Month').change(function () {
    var selectedMonth = $(this).val();
    if (selectedMonth != null && selectedMonth != '') {
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("Days")', { month: selectedMonth }, function (days) {
            var daysSelect = $('#Day');
            daysSelect.empty();
            if (days == 0) {
                daysSelect.css("visibility", "hidden");
            }
            else {
                daysSelect.css("visibility", "visible");
            }
            $.each(days, function (index, day) {
                daysSelect.append($('<option/>', {
                    value: day.value,
                    text: day.text
                }));
            });
        });
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the page where you want the code to run:

```
<script src="js_file_name.js"></script>
```

Then copy and paste your code directly into a file named `js_file_name.js`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<script type="text/javascript">` and `</script>` from the external file.

Add this to your HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="filename.js"></script>
```